# Magento Cron Schedule

Tags: magento-1.9

I've been consulting my cron jobs and they all have status pending, what do I have to do to perform these pending tasks?

```
Select * from cron_schedule
```

Comment: do you have cPanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once these lines are added to the cron table in the operating system, the cron jobs should be executed automatically:

```
* * * * * /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -mdefault
* * * * * /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -malways
```

This information is from https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron

In order to try it out manually and check for possible problems, you could run it manually via command line, which is, obviously, not a permanent solution:

```
/path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -mdefault
/path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -malways
```

Comment: when i execut this command i get this erro " -bash: api.php: command not found "

Comment: Do you have permissions to run php scripts via cli on the server you work with?

Comment: yes, i have permission

Comment: what's your operating system?

Comment: hi, im using centos 7

Answer (score 0):

Open shell (Command line) of your server

Run `sudo cat /etc/crontab` (for CentOS) to open crontab, and add following lines to schedule your cronjobs.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /RootDirectory/YouProjectDirectory/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /RootDirectory/YouProjectDirectory/var/log/magent$
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /RootDirectory/YouProjectDirectory/update/cron.php >> /RootDirectory/YouProjectDirectory/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.1 /RootDirectory/YouProjectDirectory/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /RootDirectory/YouProjectDirectory/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Save file after after adding above lines

Note: **RootDirectory** is your server root path and **YouProjectDirectory** is your magento root directory

Here is cron scheduling tutorial:
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/automate-system-tasks-using-cron-on-centos-7/